# How can I use Active Admin's form block to update a table that tracks when an attribute in a resource is updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

How can I use Active Admin's form block to update a table that tracks when a particular attribute in the current resource is updated?

For instance, I have something like this:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :address
    f.input :zip
    f.input :city
    f.input :active_state, as: :select, collection: active_states
    f.input :approval_state, as: :select, collection: approval_states
    f.input :new_comment
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

where everything but `new_comment` is an attribute that exists on the current resource.

I tried doing something like this in the class for the resource:

```
def new_comment
  history = History.new(:id, Time.now)
  history.comment
end
```

I also tried creating a controller instance variable when that failed, but that didn't work either. The venue class doesn't really have any co-relation to the history class. I'm just trying to create an input column that will create a new row in my History table whenever the user edits a venue and then adds a comment.

The History model looks like this:

```
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :venue_id, :created_at
  belongs_to :venue

  def initialize(id, datetime)
    @id = id
    @datetime = datetime
  end
end
```

The form is for a Venue that looks like this:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :address, :zip, :city
 has_many :histories
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :histories
 //with a bunch of methods
end
```

I tried doing this after some digging but it didn't work either:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :address
    f.input :zip
    f.input :city
    f.input :active_state, as: :select, collection: active_states
    f.input :approval_state, as: :select, collection: approval_states
  end
  f.inputs "History" do
    f.has_many :histories do |h|
        h.input :id
        h.input :comment
        h.input :modified_at
    end
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Comment: Please post both models, the one for the form and also `History`.

Comment: You're lacking an association between the `Venue` model and the `History` model. Take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: thanks! that seems to have gotten me further but I'm still getting this error: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I made some corrections to your ActiveAdmin resource.

Comment: I think the error you're getting is because of that `#initialize` method. ActiveRecord actually takes care of that for you, so unless you have a strong reason to use a constructor you're better off without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting up the model relationships and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, try this in your ActiveAdmin resource:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :name
    f.input :address
    f.input :zip
    f.input :city
    f.input :active_state, as: :select, collection: active_states
    f.input :approval_state, as: :select, collection: approval_states
    f.has_many :histories do |h|
      h.input :id
      h.input :comment
      h.input :modified_at
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: Made this change and am currently getting the error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)" at the 'f.has_many' block

Comment: Can you update your question with the model associations and the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` statement?

Comment: This actually worked, thanks a lot. You're awesome!
I had an initialize function in my model that's why I was getting the error I commented on but I can take it from here.